# How do you detect UniqueConstraintError in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to retry creating record in case unique attribute is already there, so how do I check if failure to create new record is due to UniqueConstraintError.

I'm trying to find an example code but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: Could you share sample code of the model you're trying to create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Model.create(objectToCreate)
      .catch(sequelize.UniqueConstraintError, () => { // TODO });
```

If you use `bulkCreate` you can use boolean property in option `ignoreDuplicates` (not supported by Postgres) or `updateOnDuplicate` (only supported by MySQL)

Comment: Thank you. I was doing some weird acrobatics like searching of word unique in error message using regex. This looks so less retarded

Comment: never seen this to work on NodeJS. which version is it?

Comment: @Kostanos it's thx to sequelize (return bluebird promise) http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html

Answer (score 7):

```
import {UniqueConstraintError} from 'sequelize'

Model
.create({...})
.then(obj => {})
.catch(err => {
    if(err instanceof UniqueConstraintError){
        throw new Error('duplicate error')
    }
    else{
        throw err
    }
})
```

If you also need the field name (which caused this error) this might help

```
err.errors[0].path
```